# Descent of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions

If a finite group acts $G$ on a variety $X$, consider the quotient $X/G$. I would like to understand which line bundle on $X$ descends to $X/G$. The action is not free. Can anyone direct me to some reference?

Comment: See page $106$ of Vistoli's notes on descent. There is a notion of equivariant line bundle (or more generally, sheaf; see wikipedia), and I think $L$ probably descends to $X/G$ iff $L$ is $G$ equivariant.